# Is it good practice to use <iostream> or <stdio.h> in C++?

Tags: c++

I am new to C++ and tutorials use both `<iostream>` and `<stdio.h>`. Which one would be best to use?

Comment: Be careful with C++ tutorials. Don't confuse C and C++. Look for tutorials made after 2011 as the language changed a lot year. Tutorials that use `#include <something.h>` tends to indicate that the tutorial is meant for C instead of C++ since standard C++ header includes don't end in `.h`.

Comment: First of all, if you use `<stdio>`, I would recommend using the c++ standard library `<cstdio>`, which would work with inputs of c++ classes.

Comment: Unrelated: @Ella I would recommend learning C++ using [good C++ books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) instead of videos.

Comment: The C++ I/O allows for overloading `operator>>` and `operator<<` for customized structs and classes.  The C I/O system is restricted to the primary types.  My recommendation is to stay with the C++ I/O system (and stay away from online judges).

Comment: Note: If your tools are up-to-date you may find `<format>` easier to use than both.

Answer (score 2):

This leans heavily into opinion, but `<stdio.h>` is a C header, so generally the answer would be `<iostream>`. If you feel the need to use the C header in a C++ program, include it this way:

```
#include <cstdio>
```